# How to select repeated words in an R column as a list

Tags: r, list, tm

I have a dataframe

```
 DF<- slNo names  
       1      get
       2      free
       3      new
       4      get
       5      new
```

I want to obtain a list of the words used in the names column

```
  list<- c(get, free, new)
```

I can use tm package to create a term document matrix for this but that seems long and awakward. is there a simpler more elagant way to achieve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `unique` to get a `vector` of `set` of 'names'

```
v1 <- unique(DF$names)
v1
#[1] "get"  "free" "new"
```

if we need to store is a `list`

```
lst <- as.list(unique(DF$names))
```